# TypeScript Generics always showing as "any" in VS Code

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm using TypeScript 2.5.3 with VS Code 1.16.1 and I'm trying to make a generic function that will accept an event handler where one of the arguments is a specific type, and it should call a callback of another type when done.

Example:

```js
router( 'staff-count', async function<String, Number>(locals, payload, cb) {
    let staff = new Staff();
    cb( await staff.count() );
} );
```

My interface looks like this:

```js
export interface SocketCallback<T> {
    (json: T): void;
}

export interface SocketRouter {
    (
        eventName: string,
        handler: {
            <TdataIn, Tcallback>(
                e: SocketLocals,
                payload: TdataIn,
                callback: SocketCallback<Tcallback>
            ): Promise<void>;
        }
    ): void;
}
```

So I'd expect `payload` to be a `String` and the callback to take a `Number`.

However, in VSCode, it shows all three documents for the callback to be `:any`. If I remove the generic `<String, Number>` it shows the datatypes of `TdataIn` and `Tcallback`, the `locals` and `cd` are also correctly types.

How can I make it so that the `payload` is of type `String` in this case (it will actually be a JSON object, but to keep it simple...).

Thanks!

**Edit**

Code to work as an example in VS Code - remove the `<String, Number>` the the `router` call and it will show `payload` as `TdataIn` for example. Keep the `<String, Number>` there and it will show `payload` as `any`. I should be `String` I think?

```js
export interface SocketCallback<T> {
    (json: T): void;
}

export interface SocketRouter {
    (
        eventName: string,
        handler: {
            <TdataIn, Tcallback>(
                locals: string,
                payload: TdataIn,
                callback: SocketCallback<Tcallback>
            ): Promise<void>;
        }
    ): void;
}

class Staff {
    public async count (): Promise<number> {
        return 3; // would do some db interaction
    }
}

let router: SocketRouter = function ( name, cb ) {
    // Do something
}

router( 'staff-count', async function<String, Number>(locals, payload, cb) {
    let staff = new Staff();
    cb( await staff.count() );
} );
```

Comment: Do you mean `function<String, Number>(locals, payload:string, cb:number)` or something more? I tried copying your code but there are a lot of missing types. Any way you can provide a full [mcve]?

Comment: `I'm trying to make a generic function that will accept an event handler where one of the arguments is a specific type, and it should call a callback of another type when done.` <= Also why not just return a Promise or Observable? That is usually a more simple and flexible solution that providing callbacks. The signature would be `router(input:string): Promise<{locals:any, payload:string, cb:number}>`

Comment: @Igor - Thanks for your replies. I've added a full example now for VS Code. I'd like to do it with a callback as this will be running at the top level of the module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Edited

Place the generic arguments on the `SocketRouter` interface's method and then you can specify the generic constraints when you call `router`.

```
export interface SocketCallback<T> {
    (json: T): void;
}

export interface SocketRouter{
    <TDataIn, TCallback>(
        eventName: string,
        handler: {(
                locals: string,
                payload: TDataIn,
                callback: SocketCallback<TCallback>
            ): Promise<void>;
        }
    ): void;
}

class Staff {
    public async count (): Promise<number> {
        return 3; // would do some db interaction
    }
}

let router: SocketRouter = function ( name, cb ) {
    // Do something
}

router<String, Number>( 'staff-count', async function(locals, payload, cb) {
    let staff = new Staff();
    cb( await staff.count() );
});
```

*Note: I am not really a fan of this solution over what I proposed initially because you are specifying the types after you have already created the instance of `router` but that is OK depending on how you are actually using this in your code. You could also mix the above with the below, specify one generic parameter on the interface type and another on the method, again if/how you want to do that really depends on how you see yourself using this.*

---

#### Previous code

Why not place the generic arguments at the interface definition level, this would solve the problem. You would then declare the actual types when you define an instance of `SocketRouter`

```
export interface SocketCallback<T> {
    (json: T): void;
}

export interface SocketRouter<TDataIn, TCallback> {
    (
        eventName: string,
        handler: {(
                locals: string,
                payload: TDataIn,
                callback: SocketCallback<TCallback>
            ): Promise<void>;
        }
    ): void;
}

class Staff {
    public async count (): Promise<number> {
        return 3; // would do some db interaction
    }
}

let router: SocketRouter<String, Number> = function ( name, cb ) {
    // Do something
}

router( 'staff-count', async function(locals, payload, cb) {
    let staff = new Staff();
    cb( await staff.count() );
});
```

Comment: Sure, but then the `router` is not generic. If I then wanted another call to `router` it would need another variable to be defined for it - with the "Do something" logic. I'm basically trying to do something like Express' router, but I want to tell TypeScript that `payload` is going to be of a specific type, and that the callback should get a specific type. The `router` should be a generic function allowing any JSON data object in and back.

Comment: @AllanJardine - I think I understand, maybe this is what you were after?

Comment: That's the one! Thank you!

Comment: @AllanJardine - you are welcome, glad we got it sorted out :)

Answer (score 0):

Your generic is in the wrong spot.

For starters, putting generics on your `async function` at the end is meaningless, You may have meant something like `async function () { bla bla } as (something: Number, somethingElse: String) => void` (even though that too would have been meaningless)

The real issue here though is that it's the *callback* that's supposed to be generically inferred, and not the handler itself (only to pass it down to the callback).

You want something like this:

```
export interface SocketCallback {
    <T>(json: T): void;
}

export interface SocketRouter {
    (
        eventName: string,
        handler: {
            <TdataIn>(
                locals: string,
                payload: TdataIn,
                callback: SocketCallback
            ): Promise<void>;
        }
    ): void;
}

class Staff {
    public async count () { // no need to provide explicit return type. TS can infer.
        return await 3; // would do some db interaction
    }
}

let router: SocketRouter = function ( name, cb ) {
    // Do something
}

router( 'staff-count', async function(locals, payload, cb) {
    let staff = new Staff();
    cb( await staff.count() ); // works as expected
} );
```

The important parts being:

- `SocketCallback` is no longer generic, instead, *the function itself* represented by the `SocketCallback` interface is. This distinction means that the type parameter (renamed T) can be inferred by the parameters passed to the function.
- As a result, `handler` only has one generic type parameter.

Comment: Hi - thanks for your reply! With that code, VS Code sees `payload` as `TdataIn`, which is fine, but I want to let it know that it should be a specific JSON object that I've defined elsewhere as an interface. That way VS Code can do its auto complete stuff and TypeScript can do its type checking. The generics don't actually appear to be used at all in that example.

Comment: I want to be able to do something [like this](https://pastebin.com/iZhzMsmF) and it would "know" that `payload` is of type `MyJSON`.

Comment: In that case, you tell the generic function that T must extend `MyJSON` like so: `<T extend MyJSON>(json: T): void`

Comment: @"Madara Uchiha" I don't understand I'm afraid. As I understand it that would do in the `interface` definition. But I just want to be able to tell TypeScript / VSCode that `payload` is going to be of a specific JSON object for each call of the `router` function. It might be `MyJSON` for one, `StaffInfo` for another, etc. The `payload` is a JSON object that I want to enforce type checking on. I thought that was the whole point of generics, but I'm not seeing how that can work if it always gets marked as `any` as soon as I give it a type in the `<>` brackets.